# Flow formulas not working

Tags: formula, visual-workflow

I recently updated a Flow I have that creates several records based on one record being created (it's kicked off by Process Builder). This flow is triggered by the creation of a Needs Assessment (custom object), and one of the actions is to create a Build (another custom object). I wrote two formulas to add up a bunch of Number fields on the Needs Assessment and copy the sum onto a field on the Build. When I test this Flow in action however, neither Build field is being populated at all, and I'm not running into any error messages.

Now, the Formulas in question are fairly long and quite large, as they add up many many number fields (in fact, one of the two is actually summing two separate Formulas because I was hitting a character limit when I tried to do it in one), but I anticipated that I would hit an error when saving my Flow if they were actually invalid.

Does anybody know if Formulas written in visual workflow would raise an error upon saving if they were too long/large? If that's not the issue, does anyone have any other troubleshooting tips?

Comment: I want to say that while working with formulas I found that if you reference another formula then the length of the referenced formula gets added to the first. In flows they might not have built that check in and only did it for the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible workarounds.

1. On the object create a formula field or two that adds them together. You still might not be able to reference the other formulas and get it all on one field. But then you could add them up in the flow much more easily.
2. In the flow use an assignment element. Set a variable called varTotal and then each row of the assignment can add one of your values to the total. You might need to use multiple assignment elements depending on how many rows are allowed.

Comment: Decided against trying your first suggestion since there are already too many fields on my custom object -- but the second suggestion worked perfectly! Just what I needed to do. Thanks for your help in thinking creatively about this!